# Convert one Collection to another Collection (not List)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of `DateTime` named `reportLogs`. I need to create a `Collection<T>` of `ShortDateString` from this `Collection<DateTime>`. What is the most efficient way to do it?

```
Collection<DateTime> reportLogs =  reportBL.GetReportLogs(1, null, null);
Collection<string> logDates = new Collection<string>();
foreach (DateTime log in reportLogs)
{
    string sentDate = log.ToShortDateString();
    logDates.Add(sentDate);
}
```

**EDIT**:

The question is about `Collection of string`; not about `List of string`. How can we handle the Collection of string ?

**REFERENCE**:

1. [Using LINQ to convert List<U> to List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075572/using-linq-to-convert-listu-to-listt)
2. [LINQ convert DateTime to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887776/linq-convert-datetime-to-string)
3. [Convert a datetime in a subcollection of collection and use it in LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976763/convert-a-datetime-in-a-subcollection-of-collection-and-use-it-in-linq-to-sql)
4. [convert Collection<MyType> to Collection<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200770/convert-collectionmytype-to-collectionobject)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're happy with just `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
IEnumerable<string> logDates = reportBL.GetReportLogs(1, null, null)
                                      .Select(d => d.ToShortDateString());
```

You could turn this to `List<string>` easily with 1 more call

```
List<string> logDates = reportBL.GetReportLogs(1, null, null)
                                      .Select(d => d.ToShortDateString())
                                      .ToList();
```

Edit: If you *really* need your object to be `Collection<T>` then that class has [a constructor which takes `IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132401.aspx) so the following will work:

```
Collection<string> logDates = new Collection(reportBL.GetReportLogs(1, null, null)
                                      .Select(d => d.ToShortDateString())
                                      .ToList());
```

Comment: The question is about 'Collection of string'; not about 'List of string'. How can we handle the 'Collection of string' ?

Comment: @Lijo - [`List<T>` inherits `ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) - which means `List<T>` **IS** a Collection!

Comment: @Lijo - Also `Collection<T>` has a constructor which takes `IList<T>` - so you can always pass the list to the result of the above to a new Collection. I'll update the answer with this.

Comment: @Lijo - I struggle to think of a better way. Whatever you do, you will need to create a new instance of `Collection<T>` and fill it. This solution just does that bit by augmenting the original Collection

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398903/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-t-and-collectionof-t

Comment: @Jamiec  *List<T> inherits ICollection<T> - which means List<T> IS a Collection*. No, Collection<T> is different from `ICollection<T>`

Comment: @nawfal - I fail to see your point. The fact that `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` means that for all intents and purposes you can treat a list as a collection. That was the only point I was making.

Comment: @Jamiec the point you failed to see has been incorporated in your edited answer, hope its clear now :) When someone says *The question is about 'Collection of string'; not about 'List of string'*, I hope its clear for someone as experienced as you that the guy is talking about `Collection<T>` and not about the generic term *collection*, especially given the code already.

Answer (score 0):

```
var logDates= reportLogs.Select(d => d.ToShortDateString());
```

Optionally you can add a `.ToList()`

Comment: `logDates` was the destination, not the source.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Create a collection of DateTime
```

DateTime obj =new DateTime(2013,5,5);

```
List<DateTime>lstOfDateTime = new List<DateTime>()
{
  obj,obj.AddDays(1),obj.AddDays(2)


};
```

use List class **convertAll** Method to convert to ShortDateString

//Convert to ShortDateString

```
   Lis<string> toShortDateString =  lstOfDateTime.ConvertAll(p=>p.ToShortDateString());
```